# Is there a way in Angular to get the id of own element in the html?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm tring to get the id of an element inside the same element in the HTML part of the component, so it would be something like this:

```
<div id="elementId">{{this.id}}</div>
```

When it is compiled the html should show:

```
<div id="elementId">elementId</div>
```

There's a way to do this in Angular?

Added:
The problem to solve is having a lot of very similar elements with many references to the id but not having a pattern to make an ngFor. E.g.:

```
<mat-grid-tile id="id1" colspan="4" rowspan="8" [ngClass]="{'selected': data['id1'].select===true,'disabled':data['id1'].open===0}" style="background: darkviolet;" class="hour"><span>{{data['id1'].name}}</span><small>{{data['id1'].time}}</small></mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile class="empty" colspan="4" rowspan="4"></mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile id="id2" colspan="2" rowspan="4" [ngClass]="{'selected': data['id2'].select===true,'disabled':data['id2'].open===0}" style="background: deeppink;" class="hour"><span>{{data['id2'].name}}</span><small>{{data['id2'].time}}</small></mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile id="id3" colspan="2" rowspan="4" [ngClass]="{'selected': data['id3'].select===true,'disabled':data['id3'].open===0}" style="background: violet;" class="hour"><span>{{data['id3'].name}}</span><small>{{data['id3'].time}}</small></mat-grid-tile>
...
```

I would like to change the 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'... for a dynamic get of the id, and the use of template variables would cause the same problem.

Comment: Are you defining the id of the html element, or you are trying to grab dynamically generated id?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the element ID with the use of a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables):

```html
<div id="elementID" #el>{{ el.id }}</div>
```

`#el` declares a template variable that holds a reference to its host element.